# How can pandas.read_sql_query() query a TEMP table?

Tags: sql, python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy, netezza

I'm in the process of converting Python code over to the new SQLAlchemy-based Pandas 0.14.1.

A common pattern we use is (generically):

```
connection = db.connect()  # open connection/session

sql = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 AS SELECT ...'
connection.execute(sql)

... other sql that creates TEMP tables from various joins of previous TEMP tables ...

sql = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE tableN AS SELECT ...'
connection.execute(sql)

result = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tableN WHERE ...')

connection.close()
```

Now, once the connection is closed the TEMP tables are purged by the DB server.  However, as the final select query is using the same connection/session, it can access the tables.

How can I achieve similar using SQLAlchemy and pd.read_sql_query() ?

For example:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('netezza://@mydsn')
connection = engine.connect()

sql = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE tmptable AS SELECT ...'
connection.execute(sql)

result = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM tmptable WHERE ...', engine)
```

yields a DB error that the TEMP table tmptable doesn't exist.  Presumably this is because passing the engine to the read_sql_query() requires it to open a new connection which has an independent session scope and hence can't see the TEMP table.  Is that a reasonable assumption?

Is there a way to work around that?  (passing the connection to read_sql_query() isn't supported)

(I know that I can concatenate the SQL into a single string with ; separating the statements, but this is a simplification of the actual situation where the TEMP tables are created by a multitude of functions which call others nesting 3-4 deep. So, to achieve that would require implementing a layer than can coalesce the SQL across multiple calls before issuing it, which I'd rather avoid implementing if there is a nicer way)

Using -
Pandas: 0.14.1
sqlalchemy: 0.9.7
pyodbc: 3.0.6
Win7 x86_64 Canopy Python distribution (Python 2.7.6)
Josh Kuhn's Netezza SQLAlchemy dialect from https://github.com/deontologician/netezza_sqlalchemy

Comment: Can you open a github issue for this as an enhancement request? See https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: See further https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8533

Comment: Hi DavidJ, according to the accepted answer, do you know when the connection will be closed and thus the temp table deleted? Like, if I would like to use that temp table in multiple `pd.read_sql()` queries how would I do? Thanks!

Comment: @crash The connection would need to be explicitly closed with something like: `connection.close()` so you should be able to query the temp table for as long as your session is still active.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can now pass SQLAlchemy connectable to `pandas.read_sql`. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

> pandas.read_sql(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, columns=None, chunksize=None)
>
> ...
>
> con : SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI
>
> or DBAPI2 connection (fallback mode)
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that > library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.

So, this should work:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('netezza://@mydsn')
connection = engine.connect()

sql = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE tmptable AS SELECT ...'
connection.execute(sql)

result = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM tmptable WHERE ...', con=connection)
```

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is add 'SET NOCOUNT ON' at the beginning of your query, that way pandas read_sql will read everything as one statement.

```
sSQL = '''SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE ...... '''
```

Comment: Carlos, I use this all the time for complex multi-statement queries on MS SQL Server.  Thanks for pointing out such a simple but effective setting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python and Netezza, I was using R and SQL Server, so this might be different.  In my script, I ran into a similar issue.  `sp_execute_external_script` in T-SQL which allows for external code to run on the database only allows for `select` statements.  This was burdensome for me because I wanted to run a stored procedure to create a temp table to select from.  Alternatively, I could use common table expressions, unions, etc.  It might be worth further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the issue, but is creating regular tables not working? You could come up with a convention such as `CREATE TABLE TEMP_t1' etc., and`DROP` them at the end of your session.

Answer (score 0):

As @ssharma says, you can now pass SQLAlchemy connectable to pandas.read_sql. 
If you create the session with the session maker, you need the connection object.

For reading the uncommited changes you have to use the same connection like this:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('netezza://@mydsn')
session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)()

sql = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE tmptable AS SELECT ...'
session.execute(sql)

result = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM tmptable WHERE ...', con=session.connection())
```